# Can not enter text in input box using sendkeys or javascript in IE11

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I am trying to enter text into input box using sendkeys or javascript. I can see value entered into input field but when clicking on search button then I am getting an error message that input field cannot be blank.

html is

> > input id="inputMId" class="" type="text" data-bind="value: mId, onMFieldFocusOut: MId,css{datePicker:isMIdError()}" maxlength="15"
> >         span class="validationMessage" style="display: none;"
> >  span id="MErrorMessage" class="validationMessage"
> >     data-bind="text:mErrorMessage,visible:isVisibleMErrorMessage()"
> >     style="display: none;"

The code I tried is

```
element.sendKeys("value")
```

and

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('inputMId').value='"+testData.get("MId")+"';");
```

I am trying this on Internet Explorer 11 using serenity framework. 
Above code works perfectly fine on chrome

Comment: Can you remove the markups and update the question with a text based formatted `HTML` with all the `<input>` and `<span>`  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, below things worked for me.

```
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Transferable stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
element.click();
Robot r;
try {
r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
} catch (AWTException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not sure whether this code will run successfully using Jenkins or not, locally it is working very fine

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem with IE a quick work around I used was to

- Use the java script executor to scroll the element into view
- Perform a SendKeys() action
- Put focus on the text field
- Lastly take focus off (blur) the element

I use this to try replicate actual user interactions

Although I would be interested to know the reason why a simple SendKeys() action will work on Chrome but not IE

Comment: Another option could be to try do a element.SendKeys(Key.Tab);